# How can I sepearate objects into individual files?

Tags: objects

I started modeling a rifle, and I also did a sight with it.

The thing is: I want to make both the sight and the rifle into 2 individual files. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Are you sure you mean individual files, e.g. separate blend files, and not just separate objects?

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of your question is to manage your items separately I would recommend making groups - which is done by selecting the objects and CTRL G. The advantage of this is you can choose to have one file with them both linked in, and the other two groups appended into separate blend files. This gives you the freedom to work on them separately and then just update the mother files...as it were.

Answer (score 0):

In edit Mode, select the vertices that you want to separate and press <kbd>P</kbd>, choose *selected* fom the menu.

That will create a new object from the selected vertices.